# Web.config changing file default location

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I've have a tricky question for you:

In `Visual C# IDE`, how do you change the location of a file within a seperate folder?

So for example

The inital path of this folder was Webproject/folder1/Default.aspx in VS 2008, I converted this to 2010 and needed to rename the Default.aspx to folder1Default.aspx to make it work in 2010, because I couldnt have more than one Default.aspx. Now when I attempt to navigate to this folder, it can't open this as the default page. 
How can I set this page to be the default location for this specific folder?
If the path were Webproject/folder1/folder1Default.aspx, how could I
change this location using the web.config file?

Thanks.

Comment: if I'm understanding your question correctly: you drag the file to the target folder in your Solution Explorer and edit your web.config file

Comment: It's ***really unclear*** what you're trying to accomplish. Please update the question so that we can get a much deeper understanding of your **overall goal.**

Comment: This sounds like a X Y Problem - Please explain your overall purpose.  There might be easier ways to accomplish this.

Comment: Added more information

Comment: Are you asking how to set the starting web-page in VS2010?

Comment: Figured it out, this works.

<location path="folder1">
      <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument enabled="true">
          <files>
            <add value="folder1Default.aspx"/>
          </files>          
        </defaultDocument>        
      </system.webServer>      
  </location>

Comment: If someone wants to post that as the answer, it wont let me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did this, but there should be only 1 default or index file which are defined in IIS or config file.

```
<location path="folder1">
     <system.webServer> 
       <defaultDocument enabled="true">
         <files> 
          <add value="folder1Default.aspx"/> 
         </files> 
       </defaultDocument> 
     </system.webServer> 
    </location>
```

I have done it like this in config file

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <remove value="default.aspx" />
        <remove value="iisstart.htm" />
        <remove value="index.html" />
        <remove value="index.htm" />
        <remove value="Default.asp" />
        <remove value="Default.htm" />
        <add value="folder1Default.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
```